# This set of matrices whose eigenvalues have non-zero real part is dense

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to prove the set of the matrices whose eigenvalues have non-zero real part is an dense subset of $M^n$, the set of square matrices with order $n$ which is identify with $\mathbb R^{n^2}$.

I almost sure this is a very known fact, I would like to know where I can find this theorem or how can I prove it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

One way: take a matrix $A \in M^n$. Write $A = S B S^{-1}$ where $B$ is the the Jordan normal form of $A$. The eigenvalues of $B$ (and also $A$) are the diagonal entries of $B$. By changing $B$ a little bit (to $B'$ say), you can make all its eigenvalues have nonzero real part *without putting it out of Jordan normal form*. Since conjugation by $S$ is continuous, you can also ensure that $A' = S B' S^{-1}$ is quite close to the original $A$.

Comment: Actually, the thing I put in italics for emphasis is sort of irrelevant since similarity preserves eigenvalues... But any reasonable choice of perturbation $B'$ is probably still Jordan normal anyway.

Comment: when you say close, which norm are you using?

Comment: There's a sense in which the choice is irrelevant which you might encounter later on. All norms on a finite dimensional vector space (such as $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$) are "equivalent". Depending which norm you take, certain facts might be harder to verify. For example, if you use $\|A\| = \sup |a_{ij}|$ it takes a short calculation to see that $A \mapsto SAS^{-1}$ is continuous. If you use the operator norm, it is more clear. If you use the spectral norm, then $A \mapsto SAS^{-1}$ is norm-preserving!

Answer (score 1):

For $A=(a_{ij})$ we can choose the norm 
$$||A||=\sup(a_{ij})$$
and recall that in finite dimensional space all norms are equivalent.

Now pick $A\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ and let $A_k=A-\frac{1}{k}I$. Clearly $A_k\to A$ and $\det(A_k)=\det(A-\frac{1}{k}I)$ can not take more than $n$ times the value $0$ so for $k\geq k_0$     $\det(A_k)\neq0$ and then $A_k$ is invertible.

Comment: why did you choose this norm?

Comment: As I said you can choose any norm but if we want verify that $A_k\to A$ it seems to me that the chosen norm is the best.

Comment: Since @user42912 wants the eigenvalue's real parts nonzero (not just nonzero eigenvalues), mention of the determinant is a bit misleading. Of course not much needs to change: if $A$ has set of eigenvalues $\Lambda$, then $A + 1/k$ has set of eigenvalues $\Lambda + 1/k$. Most of those translates won't intersect the imaginary axis.